# Use wildcard subdomains on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify, namecheap

I'm using a react application which I deploy on netlify and make accessible via a specific subdomain (app.domain.com).

Now I would like to create separate subdomains for each of my customers (customer1.domain.com, customer2.domain.com etc.). However, I want to use the same react application (same git repository / same branch) for all of these subdomain. The react application logic should decide what content to display on the different subdomains.

My questions are:
- What do I need to configure in the netlify dns panel?
- What do I need to configure on namecheap?

Comment: did you ever find the answer? I'd like to know as well

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is possible on Netlify; however, it currently requires a [pro plan](https://www.netlify.com/pricing/#teams) as well as custom approval from Netlify's Support Team on a per-site basis, as indicated by Netlify's Director of Support on [this thread](https://community.netlify.com/t/wildcard-subdomains-redirects/469)